# RxJava Operator for switching method

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android

Im new with Rxjava on Android Project, here my code

```
class RadioListRepositoryImpl(private val apiServices: ApiServices, private val chlDao: ChannelDao) : RadioListRepository {

private val results: MutableList<DataResponse>

init {
    results = ArrayList<DataResponse>()
}

override fun getData(): Observable<DataResponse> {
    return dataFromMemory().switchIfEmpty(dataFromNetwork())
}

override fun dataFromMemory(): Observable<DataResponse> {

    val cacheDateExp = DateTime().minusHours(6)

    if(chlDao.isCacheExpired(cacheDateExp).isNotEmpty()){

        Logger.d("Get data from cache SQLITE")

        val chList: MutableList<DataResponse> = ArrayList()

        val cache = chlDao.loadAll()
        repeat(cache.size){ i ->
            val ch = DataResponse()
            ch.channelId = cache[i].channelId
            ch.channelTitle = cache[i].title

            chList.add(ch)
        }

        return Observable.from(chList)
    }else{
        chlDao.deleteAll()

        return Observable.empty<DataResponse>()
    }
}

override fun dataFromNetwork(): Observable<DataResponse> {
    val dttime = DateTime()
    return apiServices.getChannelList()
            .concatMap {
                dataListResponseModel -> Observable.from(dataListResponseModel.radio)
            }
            .doOnNext {
                channelDataResponse -> results.add(channelDataResponse)
            }
            .doOnNext { channelDataResponse ->
                Logger.d("Put data to cache")
                val c: ChannelEntitiy = ChannelEntitiy()
                c.channelId = channelDataResponse.channelId
                c.title = channelDataResponse.channelTitle
                chlDao.insert(c)
            }
}
```

}

My other class access method getData() and I want if data is empty from memory (sqlite) then get data from network.

But what I want is if data is empty from memory then get data from network insert to memory and after that getData() method return dataFromMemory()

Can I handle it using another Rx operator to simplify my code ?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

When you want to get data from multi-sources, `concat` and `first` should suit for you.

```
// Our sources (left as an exercise for the reader)
Observable<Data> memory = ...;  
Observable<Data> disk = ...;  
Observable<Data> network = ...;

// Retrieve the first source with data
Observable<Data> source = Observable  
  .concat(memory, disk, network)
  .first();
```

`concat()` takes multiple `Observables` and concatenates their sequences. `first()` emits only the first item from a sequence. Therefore, if you use `concat().first()`, it retrieves the first item emitted by multiple sources.

The key to this pattern is that `concat()` only subscribes to each child Observable when it needs to. There's no unnecessary querying of slower sources if data is cached, since `first()` will stop the sequence early. In other words, if memory returns a result, then we won't bother going to disk or network. Conversely, if neither memory nor disk have data, it'll make a new network request.

Note that the order of the source `Observables` in `concat()` matters, since it's checking them one-by-one.

Then if you want to save data for each sources, just change a little bit it your source with `doOnNext()`

```
Observable<Data> networkWithSave = network.doOnNext(data -> {  
  saveToDisk(data);
  cacheInMemory(data);
});

Observable<Data> diskWithCache = disk.doOnNext(data -> {  
  cacheInMemory(data);
});
```